# i am having this error in my Qbcore (fivem) server on the qb-multicharacter script

Tags: javascript

i am having this error in my Qbcore (fivem) server on the qb-multicharacter script

it was working normally in the past days but today started facing this problem

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘firstname’) (@qb-multicharacter/html/vue.js:6)

i reinstalled the qb-multicharacter script but nothing fixed am getting the same error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ykV8.jpg)

this is the script link in github in case you need to take a look in the vue.js

[qb-multicharacter github](https://github.com/qbcore-framework/qb-multicharacter)

(i did not make any changes on my sctript files)

Thanks!

i reinstalled the qb-multicharacter script but nothing fixed am getting the same error

it should not be stuck on the loading characters screen it must show a list of characters the player have.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is with your database connection. Make sure your database is working and the connection has been set to correct database in server.cfg. Also make sure you have your database online for example running in xampp. Also make sure oxmysql starts before multicharacter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).